# Getting today's date in java - I've tried the regular ways

Tags: java, date

I need today's date - and zero anything else (" 05/06/08 00:00:00 ")

I've tried

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);        
Date date1 = calendar.getTime();                             
System.out.println(date1);
```

Run: (This is seriously messed up)

If the hour on the computer is < 12:00 at noon :  Sun Mar 08 00:44:39 IST 2009

If the hour on the computer is > 12:00 at noon : Sun Mar 08 12:46:53 IST 2009

So I gave this up.

All the Date's setters are deprecated (except the epoch time) - so I don't want to use them either

The only thing I could think of is

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String sDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
Date today = dateFormat.parse(sDate);
```

But this is such a lame code I can't bring myself to write it.

Any other option?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a quick google for this, can't believe there is no built in method for just grabbing the date. Seems like an obvious method or property to have. Not used Java in a while though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227007/resetting-the-time-part-of-a-timestamp-in-java Addresses the same problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My standard advice for Java date/time questions: don't use `java.util.{Calendar,Date}`. Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html). That way you can represent a date as a [date](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (with no associated time zone), instead of a date/time. Or you could use a [`DateMidnight`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) if that's what you want to represent. (Be careful of combinations of time zone and date where there *is* no midnight though...)

What do you need to use the `Date` with? If you can get away with changing to use Joda throughout, that's great. Otherwise, you can use Joda to do what you want and then convert to milliseconds (and then to `java.util.Date`) when you really need to.

(Michael's solution when using `Date`/`Calendar` is fine if you really want to stick within a broken API... but I can't overstate how much better Joda is...)

Comment: SO Rule # 1: If the question is about java dates, somebody will suggest Joda Time.  Rule # 2: If the question is about javascript, somebody will suggest jquery.  Any others?

Comment: @Paul: SO Rule # 3: If the question is about regular expressions, somebody will break out the "now you have two problems" quote.  Rule # 4: If the question is about programming books, we'll get the same list of books we always get.

Comment: I only clicked on this question to see if anyone had suggested Joda Time yet (really!). :D

Comment: How can that be that so many people knows so much about the "best way" to get the current date or time, and no article exists in SO to summarize this knowledge in a simple question "How to get Date and Time in Java?" with a single and protected answer stating how to get Date and Time with standard Java API, and in comment a reference to JodaTime... instead learners like me are moved around with no clear answer... just a suggestion.

Comment: @Approachingminimums: I suspect it's partly because the *exact* answer will depend on the exact requirements. But starting off by moving to Joda Time or Java 8's java.time API is always a good bet...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still with Java 7. Not sure the best approach for me to learn Java would be to use an external library. What would be the best way with standard APIs to print "Today is May 22, 2014 and it is 12:02"?

Comment: @Approachingminimums: Always in a fixed locale? Always using a fixed format? In what time zone? These are the kinds of questions you need to ask yourself - and that's precisely why there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer. If you have a specific situation which you *don't* believe is answered elsewhere, ask a new question (but probably link to questions that are similar without helping you, as evidence that you really have looked first...)

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804371/how-to-print-at-the-console-today-is-may-22-2014-and-it-is-204-pm

Answer (score 26):

I use this:

```
public static Date startOfDay(Date date) {
   Calendar dCal = Calendar.getInstance();
   dCal.setTime(date);
   dCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
   dCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   dCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   dCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

   return dCal.getTime();
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use [HOUR_OF_DAY](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) instead of [HOUR](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) and combine it with MINUTE and SECOND also.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import static java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
import static java.util.Calendar.MINUTE;
import static java.util.Calendar.SECOND;
import static java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND;

public class Today { 
    public static void main( String [] args ) { 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set( HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
        cal.set( MINUTE, 0 );
        cal.set( SECOND, 0 );
        cal.set( MILLISECOND, 0 );
        System.out.println( cal.getTime() );
    }
}
```

The results you are getting are due to HOUR is used to AM/PM while HOUR_OF_DAY is 24 hrs.

**HOUR_OF_DAY:**

> *Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.*

**HOUR:**

> *Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.*

Answer (score 9):

The time component is not just hours (and Calendar.HOUR  is, as you have noticed, AM/PM).
You need to set *all* of the time fields to 0: HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND.

Comment: And as you can see , I've tried this , but it doesn't work (if zeroing "HOUR" alone causes different results based on the server time , what good will the rest do?)

Comment: No, you have NOT tried this. HOUR is the wrong field, use HOUR_OF_DAY!

Answer (score 4):

See [Apache's commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Calendar,%20int)) DateUtils.truncate()

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

The modern Date-Time API has [many types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) which truly represent a date or time or date-time in a specific timezone. You can choose from the following options as per your specific requirement:

1. If you are looking for a type that represents [a date without a timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/date.html), you can use [`LocalDate.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now--). The good news is that its variant, [`LocalDate#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) returns the current date from the system clock in the specified time-zone.
2. If you are looking for an object that represents a date without a timezone, and with time units set to zero, you can call [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) on the object obtained with **Option#1**.
3. If you are looking for an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) representing the Date-Time object obtained with **Option#2**, you can attach this object with `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")` using [`LocalDateTime#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to obtain a `ZonedDateTime` and convert the same into an `Instant` using [`ZonedDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate todayInSystemTz = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(todayInSystemTz);

        LocalDate todayInIndia = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(todayInIndia);

        LocalDateTime todayInSystemTzWithZeroTimeUnits = todayInSystemTz.atStartOfDay();
        System.out.println(todayInSystemTzWithZeroTimeUnits);

        ZonedDateTime todayInUtcWithZeroTimeUnits = todayInSystemTzWithZeroTimeUnits.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(todayInUtcWithZeroTimeUnits);

        Instant instant = todayInUtcWithZeroTimeUnits.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Can I represent the obtained Instant in India?
        System.out.println(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")));

        // Can I represent the obtained Instant in New York?
        System.out.println(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-20
2021-06-20
2021-06-20T00:00
2021-06-20T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-06-20T00:00:00Z
2021-06-20T05:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2021-06-19T20:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3HOPKS)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`<sup>**</sup>, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

<sup>**
A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.</sup>

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you should use

```
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY
```

As opposed to

```
Calendar.HOUR
```

Also you need to clear out the other fields (`Calendar.MINUTE`, `Calendar.SECOND`, and `Calendar.MILLISECOND`) by setting them to zero.

Sorry there's no easy way here. A pain, and that's why they're working on a new API for Java 7 I believe based on Joda Time.

Answer (score 1):

...or you can do it the hacker way:

```
long MS_PER_DAY = 86400000L;
Date dateTime=new Date();
long offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dateTime.getTime());
Date date= new Date(((dateTime.getTime()+offset)/MS_PER_DAY)*MS_PER_DAY-offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, no longer active, but it came to be on the top when I searched Google.

While all advise is very good, I can't believe no one simply answered:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(date);
```

Which returns effectively, today's date.

Comment: what you printed is the full timestamp. sometime what you need is only the date in a specific hour (for sorting, for example). Secondly, Date is a very complex issue - it depends on localization, on light saving hours, and so on. If you'll read the thread, you'll get a hunch about the complexity of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why the string manipulation?

Can you not just set the values you need on the Calendar object before converting to a Date using getTime()?

Comment: If you'd look carefully , you'd see I've tried this - and it has unexpected results

Comment: @Yossale: You were using Calendar.HOUR when Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I need to read more carefully, for some reason I only saw the last part of your question. On a side note, I'd also recommend Joda Time, though always be careful in which order you manipulate the fields of the date or you can get unexpected problems in February.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for JodaTime.

java.util.Date and Calendar are so bad they are broken. (And SimpleDateFormat is rubbish too!)

For what it's worth, Java 7 will include a new date time library based strongly around JodaTime.

Comment: I get tired of hearing this repeated mindlessly. Date and Calendar are NOT broken, nor is SimpleDateFormat. They lack some features (such as the concept of a timeless date), and the API makes some simple tasks more complex than necessary, but most of the complexity is there because dates simply ARE that complex and difficult to get right!

Comment: +1 to Michael's comment - it's not broken (Because it produces correct results), it's just infuriatingly tedious to use. JodaTime is much nice r to use - even though it takes a while to get used to the different concepts that the API introduces.

The only thing that can concievably be seen as broken in the Java data time API - IMHO - is the fact that January is represented by zero. This drives me absolutely mad.

Comment: And that is, IIRC, a legacy owed to some POSIX standard.