# jpql date comparison today

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I need a jpql query to find all the LoadFileHistory which finishDate be greater than the currente date (since 00:00:00). For instance greater than 27/11/2012 00:00:00.

I already have this one "select o from LoadFileHistory o where o.finishDate = CURRENT_DATE"  but gets me nothing.

Comment: If you want those which are greater why don't you use `>` instead of `=`?

Comment: Alex the idea of put = CURRENT_DATE is that the comparison were with the date but not with the time. I mean, just 27/11/2012 not 27/11/2012 10:15:00

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should get today's date to the query like detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829510/getting-todays-date-in-java-ive-tried-the-regular-ways) (java.util.Date has the hour, minute, second too...)

The you should supply it to your query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select o from LoadFileHistory o where o.finishDate > :today ");
q.setParameter("today",todaysDateObject,TemporalType.DATE);
q.getResultList();
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is evaluated to the current date. See: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for time level filtering with date. This worked for me.

```
Date now = DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(), -15);
Query q = em.createQuery("Select u From Users u Where u.dateCreated > :today");
q.setParameter("today",now,TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

DateUtils is of apache common.

Comment: ... or you could do it without adding an external dependency and use java.time ... `Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(15))`