# How to Disable date ranges in java calendar

Tags: java, json, calendar

In my java project i want to disable a range of dates in the java calendar and could not be successful. I'm using Netbeans as my IDE and JCalendar. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            JSONObject another_json_object = vacation_home_booking_data.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
            arrays.toArray(jsons);
            String id = another_json_object.getString("id");
            String vh_id = another_json_object.getString("vh_id");
            String check_in = another_json_object.getString("check_in");
            String check_out = another_json_object.getString("check_out");
            String status = another_json_object.getString("status");
            //creating two arrays of checking and checkout
            //check_in_arr[i] = another_json_object.getString("check_in");
            //check_out_arr[i] = another_json_object.getString("check_out");
            System.out.println("ID is " + id + "vh id is " + vh_id + "check in is " + check_in + "check out is " + check_out);


             DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
             try {
             Date date1 = formatter.parse(check_in);
             Date date2 = formatter.parse(check_out);

             jCalendar1.setSelectableDateRange(date1, date2);
             jCalendar1.setBackground(Color.yellow);


             //jCalendar1.setSelectedDate();
             } catch (ParseException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Calender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             ex.printStackTrace();
             }


        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, on a GUI calendar you want to disable a date range? What do you need , a fixed date on that place?

Comment: what i want is disable the dates between start date and end date that is retrieved from a database. Yes this is a GUI calendar.

Comment: Which calendar API/Class you are using to display GUI component; may be it is an issue with simply the format of data to be set?

Comment: gyan, i used JCalendar earliea and now using the dateChooserCombo.

Answer (score 0):

Please see, if the below methods works for you:

```
  private DateChooserCombochooser; // Initialize this somewhere
  public void setMaxDate(Calendar aDate) {
        chooser.setMaxDate(aDate);
    }

    public void setMinDate(Calendar aDate) {
        chooser.setMinDate(aDate);
    }
```

Alternatively, try using `setDefaultPeriods(PeriodSet periods)` method in the API.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. I'll check it.

Comment: To get today's date - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829510/getting-todays-date-in-java-ive-tried-the-regular-ways

Comment: This code should have worked.. Could you please let me know the jar from which you are using dateChooserCombo.

Comment: No actually i want to convert the retrieved value from the database. Isn't there any easy way to do this?

Comment: What is retrieved value and what output you want?

Comment: sorry for the misspell. It should be extracted value from the Json object. Not the retrieved values from the database. I want to disable the dates from the GUI calendar which are previously booked by other customers. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are a lot confused about what you want. I give up.