# date difference in days, in Android

Tags: android

i have to find day difference between two date in android,
i find the difference in days using timemilliseconds() 
but is there any other way to find difference?

thanx in advance

Comment: Use Joda Time's Day.daysBetween().

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, advising migration to the *java.time* classes. Use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` enum method.

Comment: Similar Question, but with whole dates rather than moments: [*Android/Java - Date Difference in days*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838527/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date#compareTo(Date)

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html

or you could use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html if you need more details about the date difference, e.g http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(                             // Total count of days.
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,      // Represent a certain date.
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) // Determine today’s current date for a particular region (time zone).
)
```

## java.time

The old `Date` class is now outmoded by the *java.time* classes. And tracking date-time as a count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch is frustrating and error-prone.

Convert your `Date` objects to `Instant`. If using later versions of Android, look for new methods added to the old classes. For earlier Android, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects’ utility class for conversion.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Because the `Instant` is always in UTC, you need to adjust into a time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply to your `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you care only about entire days as defined by dates, extract `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Get your other date, such as today.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Count the total number of elapsed days using `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( localDate , today ) ;
```

If instead you want a count of years and months and days, use the `Period` class.

```
Period p = Period.between( localDate , today ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).