# How do I get difference between two dates in android?, tried every thing and post

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date, time

I saw all the post in here and still I can't figure how do get difference between two android dates.

This is what I do:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
Date diffDate = new Date(diff);
```

and I get: the date is Jan. 1, 1970 and the time is always bigger in two hours...I'm from Israel so the two hours is timeOffset.

How can I get normal difference???

Comment: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. For older Java and Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Comment: Similar Question: [*date difference in days, in Android*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5405610/642706)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997515/15005298

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You're close to the right answer, you are getting the difference in milliseconds between those two dates, but when you attempt to construct a date out of that difference, it is assuming you want to create a new `Date` object with that difference value as its epoch time.  If you're looking for a time in hours, then you would simply need to do some basic arithmetic on that `diff` to get the different time parts.

Java:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

Kotlin:

```
val diff: Long = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()
val seconds = diff / 1000
val minutes = seconds / 60
val hours = minutes / 60
val days = hours / 24
```

All of this math will simply do integer arithmetic, so it will truncate any decimal points

Comment: Can I create Date object from this info?

Comment: It is a time, not a date, what kind of date are you attempting to create?

Answer (score 62):

```
    long diffInMillisec = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

    long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffInMillisec);
    long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMillisec);
    long diffInMin = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMillisec);
    long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMillisec);
```

Comment: Requires API Level 31.

Answer (score 23):

**Some addition:** 
Here I convert string to date then I compare the current time.

```
String toyBornTime = "2014-06-18 12:56:50";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {

        Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(toyBornTime);
        System.out.println(oldDate);

        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
        long seconds = diff / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;

        if (oldDate.before(currentDate)) {

            Log.e("oldDate", "is previous date");
            Log.e("Difference: ", " seconds: " + seconds + " minutes: " + minutes
                    + " hours: " + hours + " days: " + days);

        }

        // Log.e("toyBornTime", "" + toyBornTime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: From your method i am subtracting two date current date and 10 days old date it is returning negative milliseconds. if using both current day date difference in hour are returning positive milliseconds. Why?

Comment: Change diff into :  long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
It will help.

Answer (score 15):

### java.time.Duration

Use `java.time.Duration`:

```
    Duration diff = Duration.between(instant2, instant1);
    System.out.println(diff);
```

This will print something like

```
PT109H27M21S
```

This means a period of time of 109 hours 27 minutes 21 seconds. If you want someting more human-readable — I’ll give the Java 9 version first, it’s simplest:

```
    String formattedDiff = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
            "%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds",
            diff.toDays(), diff.toHoursPart(), diff.toMinutesPart(), diff.toSecondsPart());
    System.out.println(formattedDiff);
```

Now we get

```
4 days 13 hours 27 minutes 21 seconds
```

The `Duration` class is part of `java.time` the modern Java date and time API. This is bundled on newer Android devices. On older devices, get ThreeTenABP and add it to your project, and make sure to import `org.threeten.bp.Duration` and other date-time classes you may need from the same package.

Assuming you still haven’t got the Java 9 version, you may subtract the larger units in turn to get the smaller ones:

```
    long days = diff.toDays();
    diff = diff.minusDays(days);
    long hours = diff.toHours();
    diff = diff.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = diff.toMinutes();
    diff = diff.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = diff.toSeconds();
```

Then you can format the four variables as above.

### What did you do wrong?

A `Date` represents a point in time. It was never meant for representing an amount of time, a duration, and it isn’t suited for it. Trying to make that work would *at best* lead to confusing and hard-to-maintain code. You don’t want that, so please don’t.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: I think this is the most appropriate answer. It should be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

What about using [Instant](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Instant):

```
val instant1 = now()
val instant2 = now()
val diff: Duration = Duration.between(instant1, instant2)
val minutes = diff.toMinutes()
```

You can even save your Instant using instant1.toString() and parse that string with parse(string).

If you need to support Android API level < 26 just add
[Java 8+ API desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)
to your project.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Kotlin language for Android development you can get difference in days like this:

```
fun daysDiff(c1: Calendar, c2: Calendar): Long {
    val diffInMillis = c1.timeInMillis - c2.timeInMillis
    return diffInMillis.milliseconds.inWholeDays
}
```

or if you want to get results in different type you can replace `inWholeDays` with `toInt(...)`, `toDouble(...)`, `toString(...)`.

If the only date difference you're interested in is days (let's say as a Double type result) you can create operator extension method like this:

```
operator fun Calendar.minus(c: Calendar): Double {
    val diffInMillis = timeInMillis - c.timeInMillis
    return diffInMillis.milliseconds.toDouble(DurationUnit.DAYS)
}
```

And then any operation like `calendar2 - calendar1` will return difference in days as Double.

Comment: Currently we should use `inWholeDays` instead of `inDays`.

Comment: Thank you @CoolMind, I've updated it in my response also

Comment: Good job! Probably we don't have to use `@ExperimentalTime`, I didn't check.

Comment: Checked and updated with working code.

Comment: Well done! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer based on @Ole V. V. answer.

This also works with Singular.

```
private String getDuration(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Duration diff = Duration.between(d1.toInstant(), d2.toInstant());


    long days = diff.toDays();
    diff = diff.minusDays(days);
    long hours = diff.toHours();
    diff = diff.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = diff.toMinutes();
    diff = diff.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = diff.toMillis();

    StringBuilder formattedDiff = new StringBuilder();
    if(days!=0){
        if(days==1){
            formattedDiff.append(days + " Day ");

        }else {
            formattedDiff.append(days + " Days ");
        }
    }if(hours!=0){
        if(hours==1){
            formattedDiff.append(hours + " hour ");
        }else{
            formattedDiff.append(hours + " hours ");
        }
    }if(minutes!=0){
        if(minutes==1){
            formattedDiff.append(minutes + " minute ");
        }else{
            formattedDiff.append(minutes + " minutes ");
        }
    }if(seconds!=0){
        if(seconds==1){
            formattedDiff.append(seconds + " second ");
        }else{
            formattedDiff.append(seconds + " seconds ");
        }
    }


    return formattedDiff.toString();
}
```

It works with a StringBuilder to append everything together.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this method..but don't know why I am not getting proper result

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

But this works

```
long miliSeconds = date1.getTime() -date2.getTime();
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(miliSeconds);
long minute = seconds/60;
long hour = minute/60;
long days = hour/24;
```

Comment: TimeUint - required API33

Answer (score 2):

when you attempt to construct a date out of that difference, it is assuming you want to create a new Date object with that difference value as its epoch time.

```
//get time in milliseconds
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
//get time in seconds
long seconds = diff / 1000;
//and so on
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

for more information you could use these links:

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use java.time.

[ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of java.time to Java
6 and 7.

[ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport.

Question: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using georgian calander

```
 public void dateDifferenceExample() {

        // Set the date for both of the calendar instance
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, 02,5,23,43);
        GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 04, 02);

        // Get the represented date in milliseconds
        long millis1 = calDate.getTimeInMillis();
        long millis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();

        // Calculate difference in milliseconds
        long diff = millis2 - millis1;

        // Calculate difference in seconds
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;

        // Calculate difference in minutes
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);

        // Calculate difference in hours
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

        // Calculate difference in days
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+diffSeconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` is a terrible class that was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically `ZonedDateTime`. Suggesting that old class in 2019 is poor advice. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions

```
    public static int getDateDifference(
        int previousYear, int previousMonthOfYear, int previousDayOfMonth,
        int nextYear, int nextMonthOfYear, int nextDayOfMonth,
        int differenceToCount){
    // int differenceToCount = can be any of the following
    //  Calendar.MILLISECOND;
    //  Calendar.SECOND;
    //  Calendar.MINUTE;
    //  Calendar.HOUR;
    //  Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    //  Calendar.MONTH;
    //  Calendar.YEAR;
    //  Calendar.----

    Calendar previousDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    previousDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, previousDayOfMonth);
    // month is zero indexed so month should be minus 1
    previousDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, previousMonthOfYear);
    previousDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, previousYear);

    Calendar nextDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, previousDayOfMonth);
    // month is zero indexed so month should be minus 1
    nextDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, previousMonthOfYear);
    nextDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, previousYear);

    return getDateDifference(previousDate,nextDate,differenceToCount);
}
public static int getDateDifference(Calendar previousDate,Calendar nextDate,int differenceToCount){
    // int differenceToCount = can be any of the following
    //  Calendar.MILLISECOND;
    //  Calendar.SECOND;
    //  Calendar.MINUTE;
    //  Calendar.HOUR;
    //  Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    //  Calendar.MONTH;
    //  Calendar.YEAR;
    //  Calendar.----

    //raise an exception if previous is greater than nextdate.
    if(previousDate.compareTo(nextDate)>0){
        throw new RuntimeException("Previous Date is later than Nextdate");
    }

    int difference=0;
    while(previousDate.compareTo(nextDate)<=0){
        difference++;
        previousDate.add(differenceToCount,1);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

Comment: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. For older Java and Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Comment: Is calendar class an old date-time classes?

Comment: Yes, any date-time related class found outside the `java.time` package is now legacy and should be avoided. This includes `Date` and `Calendar`, and the java.sql classes. See the Oracle Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

**written in Kotlin:**
if you need difference between 2 dates and don't care about the dates itself ( good if you need to do something in the app,based on time from other operation time that was saved in shared preferences for example).
save first time :

```
val firstTime:Long= System.currentTimeMillis()
```

save second time:

```
val now:Long= System.currentTimeMillis()
```

calculate the miliseconds between 2 times:

```
val milisecondsSinceLastTime: Long =(now-lastScrollTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get time difference between AM and PM

```
private int  getTimeDiff() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String myDate = sdf.format(systemDate);
    Date current = null;
    Date Date2 = null;
    try {
        current = sdf.parse(myDate);
        // current = sdf.parse("05:00:00 pm");
        Date2 = sdf.parse("12:00:00 am");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long millse = Date2.getTime() - current.getTime();
    long mills = Math.abs(millse);
    int Hours = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int Mins = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    long Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;
    String diff = Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs;
    int min = 60-Mins;
    if (Hours >= 12) {
        String requiredTime = 24 - Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs;
        int minutes= ((24-Hours)*60)-Mins;
        return minutes;

    } else {
        int time = 12 - Hours;
        int hours=time+12;
        int res = (hours*60);
        int minutes = res-Mins;
        return minutes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are Ok in some cases they work perfect but when there is time difference between two dates( Like I am comparing two dates with different time then the difference between two dates either will be less than 24 hours which I can't afford or greater than 24 hours ) then it will not work so here is my approach

```
    fun isSameDay(date1: Date, date2: Date): Boolean {
       val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
       return format.format(date1).equals(format.format(date2))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Answer (score -1):

shortest answer that works for me. send start and end date in millisecond.

```
public int GetDifference(long start,long end){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(start);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    long t=(23-hour)*3600000+(59-min)*60000;

    t=start+t;

    int diff=0;
    if(end>t){
        diff=(int)((end-t)/ TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))+1;
    }

    return  diff;
}
```