# Find number of seconds between two datetime strings in android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

```
            String start_time = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(STARTING_TIME));
            Log.d("timetracker","start time"+start_time);

            String stop_time = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(STOPPING_TIME));
            Log.d("timetracker","stop time"+stop_time);
```

in log i am getting this output for the above code

```
 01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): start time2016-01-07 14:36:28.000

   01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): stop time2016-01-07 14:36:40.000

   01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): start time2016-01-07 14:37:43.000

   01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): stop time2016-01-07 14:37:44.000

   01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): start time2016-01-07 14:38:26.000

   01-08 10:27:32.107: D/timetracker(29800): stop time2016-01-07 14:38:27.000
```

i need to find difference btw start_time and stop_time
eg: btw `2016-01-07 14:36:28.000 and 2016-01-07 14:36:40.000`

Comment: instead of having the date and time as strings, you need to save time in millis. It would be easy to get difference from that

Comment: follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690370/how-do-i-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-android-tried-every-thing-and-pos

Comment: first convert those string to Date object and follow the posted answers visit [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Convert both of your string in `Date` object.

```
String secondsString = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) + " seconds ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(date1);

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(date2);

long ms1 = c1.getTimeInMillis();
 long ms2 = c2.getTimeInMillis();

longdiff=ms2-ms1;

long Second=TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSecond(draftStartDiff);

Answer (score 0):

> you can convert String date to object of date in your class....

```
private Long secondsBetween(Date first, Date second)
      {
    return (first.getTime() - second.getTime())/1000;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the database compute it:

```
SELECT starting,
       stopping,
       strftime('%s', stopping) - strftime('%s', starting) AS duration
FROM ...;
```