# How to calculate the difference between two times

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I want to calculate the sleeping time of user, he should enter when he slept and when he woke up and I should calculate how many hours he slept

For example if the user enter

`His sleeping time : 11:00 pm`

`His waking up time : 7:30 am`

`The number of sleeping hours should be : 8:30 hrs`

Is there any way to make this calculation easily

This is the code

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        sleepTimeOnOffDays = cal.getTime();

    private long subtractTwoDates(Date date1, Date date2) {

            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(date1);
            calendar2.setTime(date2);
            long milsecs1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
            long milsecs2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
            long diff = milsecs2 - milsecs1;
            long dhours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

            return Math.abs(dhours);
        }
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far..

Comment: please check again

Comment: I think what you have done is pretty close. Only question would be that your algorithm would return complete hours, not minutes etc. If you want minutes etc, then you should create a new Date object from the difference and that would give you hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: but it always return wrong values, it return 8:54 instead of 8:30 , and I do not know why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get difference between two dates in android?, tried every thing and post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690370/how-do-i-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-android-tried-every-thing-and-pos) and other questions. Please search before posting a question.

Comment: It will be easier if you use java.time, I suggest [the `Duration` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Duration). Other than that your code looks correct, is there a problem? Could you please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you get 8:54 instead of 8:30 because I cannot immediately see how your code could do that?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

From Java SE 8 onwards i would like to suggest using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API. For Android users, java.time is added in [API 26+](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).

Java 8 introduced new APIs for Date and Time to address the shortcomings of the older java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

Using the java.time API calculating the duration between 2 date times is very easy.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.now();
localDateTime1 = localDateTime1.withHour(23).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);

LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.now();
localDateTime2 = localDateTime2.plusDays(1).withHour(7).withMinute(30).withSecond(0).withNano(0);

Duration diff = Duration.between(localDateTime1, localDateTime2);

String hms = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", 
                 diff.toHoursPart(),
                 diff.toMinutesPart(), 
                 diff.toSecondsPart());
System.out.println(hms);

-----------------------

Console output:
8:30:00
```

If the java.time API is not available for your project, because for example your project is not yet on API level 26, then i would recommend using the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) API as suggested by @Ole V.V in the comments below.

The Syntax is pretty much the same as the java.time API. The code snippet above works for the ThreeTen Android Backport API as well (like @Basil Bourque already mentioned) with one exception. The `Duration` class of the ThreeTen Android Backport API unfortunately does not provide helper methods for extracting the hours part, minutes part etc. from the duration object. Instead when you use the backport you need to subtract first the hours, then the minutes from the duration so only the seconds are left:

```
long hours = diff.toHours();
diff = diff.minusHours(hours);
long minutes = diff.toMinutes();
diff = diff.minusMinutes(minutes);
long seconds = diff.getSeconds();
String hms = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", 
                 hours,
                 minutes, 
                 seconds);
```

Another difference is you need to import the java.time classes from the `org.threeten.bp` package (not the `java.time` package).

If you want to use the ThreeTen Backport API, just include it's [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp) to your project.

Comment: Good suggestion. Only if you are not yet on API level 26, I suggest [ThreeTenABP, the backport of java.time](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) over Joda-Time.

Comment: sadly my current API version is 21 :(

Comment: @OleV.V. can you please provide an example of using it or documentation

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail The back-port has virtually the same API as *java.time*. When you eventually migrate away from the back-port, you’ll need do little more than change your `import` statements. So the example code seen here remains the same when using the back-port.

Comment: Sure, @AmiraElsayedIsmail. [Example: my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529971/5772882). Documentation: [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Please search for more.

Comment: You cannot reliably calculate elapsed time between moments using `LocalDateTime` class. This calculation requires a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54393033/642706) for details.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

11:00 PM to 7:30 AM = 7.5 or 8.0 or 8.5 or 9.5 or some other number of hours depending on the particular dates and time zone.

```
Duration.between(
    ZonedDateTime.of( 2019 , 1 , 23 , 23 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Africa/Cairo" ) ) ,
    ZonedDateTime.of( 2019 , 1 , 24 , 7 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Africa/Cairo" ) )
)
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/szWobW).

> PT8H30M

## Calculating elapsed time requires date, time-of-day, and time zone

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54389448/642706) by Markus Hänsel is headed the right way, but fails to account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Your Question is not quite clear. Do you mean to track the general idea of time-of-day using generic 24-hour days? Or do you mean to track actual moments, such as the time slept two days ago, the time slept yesterday, and so on?

If the latter, then you cannot use `LocalDateDate` as that class cannot, by definition, track moments. The `LocalDateTime` class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, a `LocalDateTime` represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe).

Given your example of 11:00 pm to 7:30 am, that would mean 8.5 hours in a certain time zone with no anomalies on that date. But on a day of DST cut-over that might mean 7.5 hours (“Spring ahead”), or 9.5 hours (“Fall back”). Or maybe 8.0 hours on day such as last year when [North Korea adjusted their clock](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5692721/North-Korea-adjusts-time-zone-match-Souths-ties-warm.html) by a half-hour. Or when in 2007 [Venezuela turned back time a half-hour… and then a decade later flipped back again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Venezuela#Current_standard_time). These changes happen more often than you may realize. Politicians around the globe have shown a penchant for redefining the offset of their time zone(s).

➥ The upshot is that you cannot reliably calculate elapsed time with only the time-of-day. You **must use a date and a time zone**.

## `ZoneId`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To track moments, use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. This class combines a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone.

```
LocalDate ldStart = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 1 , 23 ) ;
LocalTime ldStart = LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.of( ldStart , ltStart , z ) ;
```

And the stop time.

```
LocalDate ldStop = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 1 , 24 ) ;  // Next day.
LocalTime ldStop = LocalTime.of( 7 , 30 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ZonedDateTime.of( ldStop , ltStop , z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time using `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

I recommend you *not* report elapsed time using time-of-day format, HH:MM:SS. Instead use the standard [format defined for this purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

So, 8.5 hours would be `PT8H30M`.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = d.toString() ;  // Generate `PT8H30M`.
```

And parsing.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT8H30M" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` for getting the input. I'm using the predefined input, since you wanted the difference calculation between two given times. Here is the code fo you. Please note I have given out the answer for both 24 or 12 hours format.

**Getting the value of sleep time and waking up time**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date sleepingTime = simpleDateFormat.parse("22:00");
Date wakeUptime = simpleDateFormat.parse("07:00");
```

**For difference is less than zero, this happens in 12 hours format**

```
long difference = sleepingTime.getTime() - wakeUpTime.getTime(); 
if(difference<0) {
  Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");
  Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");
  difference=(dateMax.getTime() -sleepingTime.getTime() )+(wakeUpTime.getTime()- 
  dateMin.getTime());
}
```

**Calculating the difference**

```
//days and minutes are optional
int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / 
(1000*60);
Log.e("log_tag",hours+" hours");
```

I hope it will answer your query. Thanks :)

Comment: I will give it a try and get back to you

Comment: no it does not work, it print 15 hr it should be 8:30

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Just Try following line of code to get difference in minutes

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; // predefined method from java 6.

  private long subtractTwoDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
    Long diffInMinutes=null,diff=null;  // just  declaration of variables
    diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    diffInMinutes= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
    log.info("diff min : "+difInMin); 
    return  diffInMinutes; // returns long value in minutes.
}
```