# How to get the difference betweeen two dates (jetpack compose/kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, date

I have to calculate how many days are left between the date selected by the user through a `DatePicker` and the current date

I was trying to write something like this:

```kotlin
val simpleDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
val date = simpleDate.parse(event!!.date!!)
val diff = Duration.between(LocalDate.now(), date.toInstant())
val leftDays = diff.toDays()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get difference between two dates in android?, tried every thing and post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690370/how-do-i-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-android-tried-every-thing-and-pos)

Comment: Do you have any example input?

Comment: What is the problem? Does the code fail to compile or doesn't it provide the expected output?

Comment: The problem is that the app crash when I use it. So I think that the code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your mix of outdated (`SimpleDateFormat`, 'Date') and modern (`LocalDate`) APIs is not optimal, I think:

I would use plain `java.time` here, because…

- you can obviously use it in your application
- it has a specific class for datetime `String`s of the pattern you have shown in your question: an `OffsetDateTime` and
- there's a `java.time.Duration` which you have tried to use

Here's an example:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // example input, some future datetime
    val input = "2022-12-24T13:22:51.837Z"
    // parse that future datetime
    val offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(input)
    // build up a duration between the input and now, use the same class
    val duration = Duration.between(OffsetDateTime.now(), offsetDateTime)
    // get the difference in full days
    val days = duration.toDays()
    // print the result as "days left"
    println("$days days left")
}
```

Output:

```
110 days left
```

---

If you don't receive a datetime but a date without time (just day of month, month of year and year), then use a `LocalDate` and calculate the `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, futureDate)`

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // example input, some future date
    val input = "2022-12-24"
    // parse that
    val futureDate = LocalDate.parse(input)
    // get the difference in full days
    val days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), futureDate)
    // print the result
    println("$days days left")
}
```

Output (again):

```
110 days left
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code -**

```
        val previousTimeDouble: Double = previousTime.toDouble()
        val nowTimeDouble: Double = System.currentTimeMillis().toDouble()
        val dateNowString: String = dateNow.toString();

        val time: Long = (nowTimeDouble - previousTimeDouble).toLong()

        val difference: String= differenceBetweenTwoTimes(time)

        Log.d("difference", difference)
```

Function for converting time difference into units -

```
fun differenceBetweenTwoTimes(time: Long): String {
            var x: Long = time / 1000
            var seconds = x % 60
            x /= 60
            var minutes = x % 60
            x /= 60
            var hours = (x % 24).toInt()
            x /= 24
            var days = x
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
        }
```