# Show Date in a Textbox in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I have two Textboxes which contains dates, from calendar Dialog, the Calendar dialog shows default current Date for both TExtboxes, But I want, If a user selects a date from first TextBox(startdate) then the next Calendar Dialog for second TextBox(End Date) should not be lesser means it will always show one value greater as a default value in second Caledar Dialog. I mean to say that the End Date will always be equal or greater than start Date but never be smaller. I don't know how to achieve this?

I wish a kind favour of you regarding this subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838527/android-java-date-difference-in-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can compare the date by using `public int compareTo (Date date)` check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29