# Calculate days between two day_of_week : Android

Tags: android

I have a query regarding to find out which is day (in given list) is nearest day from today.

For example

```
day_list is Mon, Tue, Fri, Sat
and today is Wed
```

*Now If we calculate days on paper,*

```
Wed to Mon = 5 days
Wed to Tue = 6 days
Wed to Fri = 2 days
Wed to Sat = 3 days
```

*So answer will be `Fri` .*

*But in code, how can I implement this logic?* Or is there any other way to optimize its process (regarding if_else)?

Comment: I am sure you just want to get no. of days between two dates?

Comment: If this is the case then check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838527/android-java-date-difference-in-days/6406294#6406294

Comment: My question is little bit different, I have only list of some days_of_week and I have to find which is nearest from today. If using the logic of your link, my problem is solvable, please guide me how can I implement that logic.  Thank you!

Comment: Mon = 0, Tue = 1 and so on ... in your example Wed = 2 and list = [0,1,4,5] ... for each day smallest from 2[Wed] add 7 so we have [7,8,4,5] ... for each days sub Wed so we have [5,6,2,3] ... find smallest(fx. sort array and get first) in array result 2 ... add Wed result 4 ... 4 means Fri :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have in mind is below but probably you should change a little bit to fit your need.

Give your days of week number from 0 to 6.

`Sun = 0; Mon = 1; Tue = 2; etc.`

If you just have some of days, keep the numbers. For example, if you have only `Mon`, `Tue`, `Fri`, and `Sat` then keep the number respective to the days, i.e. `1`, `2`, `5`, and `6`.

Now, if you want to know the "distance" between those days from `Wed` (which has a number `3`), you can do this math:

`distance = (theNumberOfYourDayInList - 3) mod 7`

`7` is the number of the days, by the way.

So if you want to know the distance between:

`Wed` to `Mon`: `distance = (1 - 3) mod 7` which is `5`.

`Wed` to `Fri`: `distance = (4 - 3) mod 7` which is `1`.

`Wed` to `Tue`: `distance = (2 - 3) mod 7` which is `6`.

Turn those logic into codes are trivial and I think you shouldn't face any problems.

Comment: It could be very good implementation. In current I am implementing logic of selvin. And sure I will implement your logic too. +1 for simplest logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just count them

```
int Count= days(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Calendar.TUESDAY);

private int days(int Day1, int Day2) {
    int Days = 1;
    while (Day1 != Day2) {
        Day1 += 1;
        Days += 1;
        if (Day1 == Calendar.SATURDAY) Day1 = Calendar.SUNDAY;
    }
    return Days;
}
```

Comment: So check for that or initialise Days to 0.  This was an example. I'm not writing your app for you. This was modified from a function where I needed the count in the NEXT week. i.e Tues-Wed would be 8 days

Comment: I know you wont write my application. I thought it could be a good logic, but I realised that it will take some time to find its bug. Anyway thank you!