# Get Date and Time Difference in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds in Android

Tags: android

I need to get difference between current date and a date in future, in days , hours , minutes and seconds in android. Like if current date and time is 17/05/2012 03:53:00 and a date in future is 18/05/2012 04:55:00.

I need to display difference as remaining time= day: 1, hours: 1, and minutes 2.

Any kind of help will be appreciated . Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Munazza K

Comment: You may also find this post useful, as it describes correct way to calculate difference between two dates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6406294/716075

Answer (score 18):

You can do this way

```
   c_date=18/05/2012 04:55:00.  and  saved_date=17/05/2012 03:53:00

   long diffInMillisec = c_date.getTime() -saved_date.getTime();
   long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMillisec);
   seconds = diffInSec % 60;
   diffInSec/= 60;
   minutes =diffInSec % 60;
   diffInSec /= 60;
   hours = diffInSec % 24;
   diffInSec /= 24;
   days = diffInSec;`
```

Answer (score 8):

You can subtract both dates, and the calculate the differences. Kinda like this:

```
long difference = calendar.getTimeInMillis()-currentTime;

    long x = difference / 1000;
    seconds = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    minutes = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    hours = x % 24;
    x /= 24;
    days = x;
```

You can subtract the time you've already calculated. You get the hours, get the rest, do the minutes, etc.

Comment: This just gives the length of the entire time duration in different units, not a breakdown of the days, hours, and minutes remaining as the OP implies.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the same thing recently, I used JodaTime. You can download the jar and include it in your Android app from here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

```
//Create your taget date    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 15);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    Date startDate = cal.getTime();

//Use JodaTime to calculate difference
    Period period =  getTimePassedSince(startDate);

//Extract values and display
    daysTV.setText("" + Math.abs(period.getDays()));
    hoursTV.setText("" + Math.abs(period.getHours()));
    minsTV.setText("" + Math.abs(period.getMinutes()));
    secsTV.setText("" + Math.abs(period.getSeconds()));

    ...
    public static Period getTimePassedSince(Date initialTimestamp){
            DateTime initDT = new DateTime(initialTimestamp.getTime());
            DateTime now = new DateTime();
            Period p = new Period(initDT, now, PeriodType.dayTime()).normalizedStandard( PeriodType.dayTime());
            return p;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From all those responses this is what I came up to

```
fun hoursBetween(date: Date): Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(date.time - Date().time)
fun minutesBetween(date: Date): Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(date.time - Date().time) % 60
fun secondsBetween(date: Date): Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(date.time - Date().time) % 60
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) class.

With `getTime()` method, you can have the time in miliseconds of the 2 Dates. 
Then you can create another `Date` object with the amount of miliseconds results of the subtraction between both Dates.
And you'll have the amount of days, hours and minutes since the first `Date`.