# Subtracting dates in Java. Daylight Savings Time Changes

Tags: java, date

The problem is that the subtraction of the two dates leaves me double identical value.

From : Thu Nov 29 00:00:00 CET 2012

Value 121: To: Sat Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 2013

Value 122: To: Sun Mar 31 00:00:00 CET 2013

Value 122: To: Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 CEST 2013

Value 123: To: Tue Apr 02 00:00:00 CEST 2013

```
Long today = (To.getTime() - From.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid that logically? (sorry for English)

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by **double identical value**. Could you be more clear?

Comment: What is the result you expected?

Comment: Subtracting two different dates I have the same result :P

Comment: They are dates in different time zones you can't directly substract them. Apples with apples. Use Calendar to operate, then convert them out of the calendar

Comment: time zone is the same, and I use Calendar [..].add(Calendar.DATE, 1)

Comment: CET and CEST are not same thing

Comment: yes i know, whether it is the possibility of subtracting the time>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6406294/829571