# Calculate duration in miliseconds and convert to datetime

Tags: android

I have two variables - time when activity starts (`currentTime`) and time when the button is clicked (`endTime`). These variables have values in milliseconds (`System.currentTimeMillis()`). I use them in Layout so I convert these values to DateFormat `"HH:mm:ss"`.

**I want to calculate duration** (`durationTime`) between `currentTime` and `endTime` and convert it to datetime. Look please to my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            long currentTime_ms, endTime_ms;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                currentTime_ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Date currentTime = new Date(currentTime_ms);
                currentTime_textView.setText(sdf.format(currentTime));
            }

            public void btnOk_onClick(View v) {

                endTime_ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Date endTime = new Date(endTime_ms);
                Date durationTime = new Date(endTime_ms - currentTime_ms);
            }

        }
```

Finally I've got **wrong** duration. (For example I click on Button after `2 second` and get `durationTime` **02:00:02**).

Can you help me to fix the code? Or maybe there are other methods for time calculation?

Comment: First of all you have bad onClickListener. When You have activity, you have to set the listener on button:

    `Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            //code here
        }
    }`

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice. I will use OnClickListener. And what about time calculations?

Comment: It should be really simple. You have the global variables so its good. Next just look into it for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

You can get current time with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();`

- Take two timestamps (for beginning and ending) and then you'll have
  two different longs.
- Calculate the difference between them, and call this function, which will return the String that you are looking for. You can customize it as you want!!

  ```
  public String toText(long difference) {
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");

      int remaining = (int) (difference % (3600 * 1000));

      int minutes = (int) (remaining / (60 * 1000));
      remaining = (int) (remaining % (60 * 1000));

      int seconds = (int) (remaining / 1000);
      remaining = (int) (remaining % (1000));

      int cents = (int) (((int) time % 1000) / 10);

      String text = "";
      text += df.format(minutes) + ":";
      text += df.format(seconds) + ":";
      text += df.format(cents);
      return text;
  }
  ```

In your case, this should return `"00:02:00"`: 0 minutes, 2 seconds, 0 cents.

I hope this would helps!!