# Calculate difference between two calender dates in days

Tags: android, difference, android-calendar, android-date

I know there are other similar questions have been asked here before, but as far as tried them none created the desired output, e.g. difference between  02.09.2016 and 30.08.2016 should be 3 calendar days.

```
    long diff = oldDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
    long seconds = diff / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    long hours = minutes / 60;
    long days = hours / 24;

    int year = (int) diff / 365;
    int rest = (int) diff % 365;
    int month = rest / 30;
    rest = rest % 30;
    int weeks = rest / 7;
    int dayss = rest % 7;

    long diffMillis= Math.abs(oldDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime());
    long differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Log.d("ASDafldsfg", "" + days);
    Log.d("ASDafldsfg", "" + dayss);
    Log.d("ASDafldsfg", "" + differenceInDays);
```

and the output is as following while calculating difference between 30.08.16 and 03.09.16

```
D/ASDafldsfg: 3
D/ASDafldsfg: 6
D/ASDafldsfg: 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android difference between Two Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just casting double to float and then applying Math.ceil() fixed the problem,

`long diff = oldDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
 float days = (float) diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
 tv_days.setText(String.valueOf((int) Math.ceil(days)));`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  try {

    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/10/2013 11:30:10");
    Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/10/2013 20:35:55");

    obj.printDifference(date1, date2);

  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}

//1 minute = 60 seconds
//1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
//1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400
public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

    //milliseconds
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
    System.out.println("different : " + different);

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
        "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
        elapsedDays,
        elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

}
```

Output is :

```
startDate : Thu Oct 10 11:30:10 SGT 2013
endDate : Sun Oct 13 20:35:55 SGT 2013
different : 291945000
3 days, 9 hours, 5 minutes, 45 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time
>   classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still
>   providing a simple API.

Its simple to handle with date and time.

```
Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays()
```

[**Joda Demo**](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)

Comment: what type of object is "start" and "end"? @Sohail Zahid

Comment: its Date  you can see the demo app

Comment: I struggled a full day to get the JAVA date issues working - until I finally gave up and switched to JODA - all thanks to this one-liner by you, @SohailZahid.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 1.8 introduced localDate and it has made life a lot easier for people... You can use it to calculate the difference between two dates as :

classes used :

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

LocalDate dateBefore=LocalDate.of( 2016,09,02); // you can also use Month.SEPTEMBER
LocalDate dateAfter=LocalDate.of(30,08,2016); //you can also use Month.AUGUST
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter); // this is the chronounit for Days :)
```

The new time api is extremeley powerful, please do use it for convenience

**Since android does not currently support all jdk 1.8 features, the above won't be helpful, use the following instead**

```
date1 and date2 are normal Date objects obtained using calendar object initialized to your date and then Calendar.getTime()

long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

Comment: how to get "ChronoUnit" using jdk 1.8.0_60 in android studio 2.1.3

Comment: sorry check my edited answer... forgot that android stupidly now supports lambdas but not the time api...