# Difference between current date and entered date in android

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

Here I am finding the difference between the entered date and current date. I mean I am trying to find the no of days between two Dates. If both the dates are in the same month, I am getting correct value if the dates are in different months, the difference value is incorrect. I am not getting how to rectify this one.

can anyone pls help me get this one?

This is my code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  String dayDifference;

  NotificationManager manager;
  Notification myNotication;

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }//End of onBind method

  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    try {

      //Dates to compare
      String CurrentDate;
      String FinalDate = "08/24/2016";

      Date date1 = new Date();
      Date date2;

      SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

      //Setting dates
      date1.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
      CurrentDate = dates.format(date1);
      date2 = dates.parse(FinalDate);
      date1 = dates.parse(CurrentDate);

      //Comparing dates
      long difference = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
      long differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

      //Convert long to String
      dayDifference = Long.toString(differenceDates);

      Log.e("HERE.................", "HERE: " + dayDifference);
      System.out.println("..............difference date " + dayDifference);

      Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, Mnst.class);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, targetIntent, 0);
      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

      builder.setAutoCancel(true);
      builder.setTicker("Predictor");
      builder.setContentTitle("Miisky Notification");

      builder.setContentText(
          "You have " + dayDifference + " days left. Click on notification to know more..");
      builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.miilogo);
      builder.setSound(soundUri);
      builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
      builder.setOngoing(true);
      //builder.setSubText("Your vault number is " + s.vault_no);   //API level 16
      builder.setNumber(100);

      builder.build();

      //noinspection deprecation
      myNotication = builder.getNotification();
      builder.setAutoCancel(true);
      manager.notify(11, myNotication);

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + dayDifference + " Days Left ",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      Log.e("DIDN'T WORK............", "exception " + exception);
    }
  }
}
```

**Here the entered date is "08/24/2016" and the current date is "09/28/2016". I am getting 4 as the result which is incorrect. I think I have to use Calendar or something.but not getting exact way to do that one..**

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: i am using this format mm/dd/yyyy ..and i am not using hh:mm:ss..but in that link it is calculating days based on hours..i am not using hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the letter `m` is understood as minute in hour. In order to refer to month you need to use capital `M`.

Try to change your `SimpleDateFormat` to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use date to do this.Try to use Calendar like this.

```
public static final int diffOfDay(Date d1,Date d2){
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(d2);

    return c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

change

```
return c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

to get difference for date with different months

```
return c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```