# Java / Android - Calculate difference between timestamps

Tags: java, android, timestamp, long-integer, elapsedtime

I have a problem figuring out how to calculate the elapsed time between two timestamps (hours, minutes, seconds). This is the result:

```
String starttime = beginElement.getTimestamp();
String endtime = element.getTimestamp();
```

I/Start time: 1496258892612

I/End time: 1496258928999

```
long diffTime = Long.parseLong(endtime) - Long.parseLong(starttime);
```

I/Diff time: 36387

```
String elapsedtime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(diffTime)));
```

I/Elapsed time: 01:00:36

In fact, the elapsed time is just 36 seconds. It's always one hour less than the result.

How do I fix this strange issue?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the API incorrectly, parse is not what you need since that time is not related to a date but to a duration period instead....

do something like:

```
String periodAsHH_MM_SS = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffTime),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffTime) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffTime) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));

System.out.println("Duration in hh:mm:ss is: "+periodAsHH_MM_SS);
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to set GMT timezone, try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String elapsedtime = sd.format(diff);
```