# Difference between two dates in android in the formate of (years,months and days)

Tags: android

I have two dates
String dateOne="ddMMyyyy"
String dateTwo="ddMMyyyy"

I want the difference like
2years  3months  10days

How can i do that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates. Modify the code to suite it to your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

If you parse those strings into `LocalDate`, you can use the following line of code:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate)
```

You can also use this method using `between()` method:

```
public long getDaysCountBetweenDates(LocalDate dateBefore, LocalDate dateAfter) {
    return DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate);
}
```

Comment: I want days as well as years and months

Comment: Should work, did you try it? Just put 2 different dates which are at least at 1 year distance.