# Calculating dates in Kotlin using date picker

Tags: kotlin

How can I calculate the number of weeks and days from today to a chosen date on a date picker? I tried to use `weekOfMonth` and `day` properties but they don't exist.

`simpleDatePicker.weekOfMonth`
`simpleDatePicker.day`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: That really didn't answer my question, i use Kotlin and can't find the answer to my question anywhere on SO

Comment: To confirm, this is on android?

Comment: Yes I use Kotlin for Android development using android studio, I am fairly new to it though.

Comment: I am basically trying to get weekOfYear and dayOfYear from the date picker but i can't, any suggestions?