# How to calculate new Date value from a Date variable and a int variable

Tags: java, date

I am trying to create a little application which holds the data of licenses, I allow the user to input the date it was the redeemed and the license length.

I want to create a day's remaining field where the user can view how many days they have left until they have redeemed the new license.

I've used **jxDatepicker**

and have three combo boxes where the user selects the number of years, months and days the license is available for

```
int days = Integer.parseInt(cboDays.getSelectedItem().toString());
Date dRedeemed = cboDate.getDate();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
String strRedeemed = format.format(dRedeemed);
days = (years * 365) + (months * 12) + days;
```

**EDIT**

I think i have left some people quite confused. That or i don't understand how this would fix my problem. Ill try and describe in a little more detail

Scenario

User can record their license using the application, they enter the day the license was redeemed and they also input the length of the license(days).

I am trying to figure out if you are able to calculate a new date from both these variables. for example

```
days = INPUT FROM USER;    
dateRedeemed = new Date();   
newDate = dateRedeemed + days;
```

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far (in java) apart from GUI stuff?

Comment: Similar question regarding finding the difference between two dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java

Comment: @JG7 - I dont think this link will help, I only have the one Date field and then a user entry for numbers of days the license is available for. I am trying to essentially trying to do this >>>>>   Today (24/06/2019) + 700 days  = newDate <<<<<< but i dont know how to even go about doing this

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Just saw that Eduardo Eljaiek has written a brand new and modern answer for your [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739994/5772882). Amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are receiving the license-deadline somehow before (via database or similar), you can utilize the `java.time` API in order to calculate the remaining days until deadline with this little example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class StackoverflowMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // define a future deadline (hint: define some others for your test cases, too)
        LocalDate deadLine = LocalDate.parse("2019-06-29", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
        System.out.println("Days til deadline: " + getRemainingDays(deadLine));
    }

    public static long getRemainingDays(LocalDate deadline) {
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), deadline);
    }
}
```

> Please note the use of the modern API, which is recommended to use nowadays.

**EDIT**

For the case you don't want to refactor your entire code, here are two methods that handle the conversion from `java.time.LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` and back:

```
    public LocalDate toLocalDate(Date dateToConvert) {
        return dateToConvert.toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate();
    }

    public static Date toDate(LocalDate localDate) {
        return Date.from(
                localDate.atStartOfDay()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toInstant()
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date firstDate = new Date();
Date secondDate = null;
secondDate = sdf.parse("06/30/2019");
long diffInMillies = Math.abs(secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());
long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This gives you answer in days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method two find out the difference between Two dates

---

```
public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) { 
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
    System.out.println("different : " + different);

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
        "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
        elapsedDays, elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);  }
```

In the Above method, you can pass the first parameter as the current date and second parameter expiry date of license

For more refer answer of this question
[Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)