# How to convert Timestamp to Date and calculate to "time ago"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timestamp

I have a Timestamp on mysql server. Example: "2019-11-23 14:26:11". I get a Timestamp in the form of a String from the server, and further on my idea, I should convert the Timestamp to Date and then count "time ago". Please, help

Comment: which networking library you use? okhttp? retrofit?

Comment: @Fartab   I use Volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answered question solves your's also.

[Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Cast your String from the server to a Date object, then substract current day - what you got from the server.

Get current date with :

```
import java.util.Calendar

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to return the time ago text 
`setTime(Integer.valueOf(time_stamp));`

```
private String setTime(int date) {
        String time_text = "";
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

        long mills = time - date;
        int hours = safeLongToInt(mills / (60 * 60));
        int mins = safeLongToInt((mills - (hours * 3600) / (60)) % 60);

        String diff = hours + ":" + mins;

        if (hours < 24) {
            duration.setText(diff + " hours ago");
        } else {
            Date dateTemp = new Date(date * 1000L);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ");

            sdf.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
            time_text = sdf.format(dateTemp);

            return time_text;

        }
        return time_text;
    }
```

Comment: `setTime(Integer.valueOf(time_stamp));` What do you think `Integer.valueOf("2019-11-23 14:26:11")` will return?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that I thought you meant Unix Timestamp