# Problem to get the difference between two dates

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date, calculation

I want to get days between today and birthday:

Today code:

```
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String currentString = formatter.format(currentDate);
        return currentString;
```

Birthday Code:

```
 String date =  dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    datePicker1.setText(date);        
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH,month +1);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);        
    CharSequence datecharSequence = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy",calendar1);
```

Calculation Code:

```
 try {
           LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.now();
           LocalDate date2 = usrBirthDate();
           long diff = DAYS.between(date1, date2);
           Annotation.setText((int) diff);
       }
       catch (Exception exception){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Unable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

Comment: What version of java do you use? If it is 8+ you'll probably benefit from using newer date\time API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does your code work? What was your question, please? So that we can help you, please specify the desired result and paste any error messages or wrong results into your question.

Comment: Don’t try to process your dates as strings. Just like you process numbers as `int` or `double`, not as `String`, process your dates as `LocalDate` objects.

Comment: For far better ways of finding the difference, see the answer by sanjeevRm below or [my answer to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169929/5772882). For what you did wrong apart from using all the wrong classes, edit your question and specify your errors, and I can reopen it so that someone may answer that part.

Answer (score 1):

efficient way to find difference in days is by using ChronoUnit.DAYS

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.now(); // current date
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JULY, 29); //  user birth date
long diff = DAYS.between(date1, date2);
```

Comment: @sanjeevRm , i want to use user method: usrBirthDate(), not static.

Comment: @user15358848, 
date1 - today()
date2 - usrBirthDate()

Comment: you can assign usrBirthDate to date2 , `date2 = usrBirthDate();` usrBirthDate has to return LocaDate

Comment: @sanjeevRm, i've maded changes, but no result:

`LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.now();
           LocalDate date2 = usrBirthDate();
           long diff = DAYS.between(date1, date2);
           Annotation.setText((int) diff);`

Comment: can you share the are values of date1, date2 and result of diff,

Comment: This is in log error:

2021-04-18 20:28:25.416 ? E/whetstone.activity: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.miui.whetstone.server.WhetstoneActivityManagerService.enableMiuiStandby(WhetstoneActivityManagerService.java:406)
        at com.miui.whetstone.server.IWhetstoneActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IWhetstoneActivityManager.java:682)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: @sanjeevRm , seems it's value format problem: data1 - 2021-04-18; data2 - 20/5/2016

Comment: you can convert format of date1 **DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY");
  formatter.format(date1);** with this both date1 and date2 will be in **dd/MM/YYYY**

Comment: format changed, but still same error. i'll read link you've sent @sanjeevRm
tnx