# Calculate minutes between two dates

Tags: android, datetime

How can I calculate the minutes between two dates?

Start Date `20/4/2021 09:00`

End Date `28/4/2021 09:00`

The result should be `11520 Minute`

I want the minutes only without calculate days, hours or seconds, How can I do like this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: @kelvin Yes but I want it to calculate minutes only, Anyway I found the answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert date to milliseconds and then subtract and convert back to minutes.

for eg,

```
long startDateMillis = startDate.getTime();
long endDateMillis = endDate.getTime();

long diffMillis = startDateMillis - endDateMillis;

long minutes = (diffMillis/1000)/60;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ZonedDateTime.until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method like this:

```
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 4, 20, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 4, 28, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
long mins = start.until(end, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println(mins);
```