# How to make End Date 1 day after the Start Day on android datePicker

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

i have a project that should bring end date after the start date on android datepicker.
(user will chose any date on start date and  when user click end date what ever user choose end date should be one day after start date)

for this purpose i have a Kotlin code as in below;

```
private fun showDatePickerDialog(type: Int) {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    year = calendar!!.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    month = calendar!!.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    dayOfMonth = calendar!!.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        requireContext(), R.style.MyDatePickerStyle,
        { datePicker, year, month, day ->
            if (type == 0){
                var month = month + 1
                var startMonthConverted = ""+month
                var startDayConverted = ""+day
                if(month<10){
                    startMonthConverted = "0$startMonthConverted"
                }
                if(day<10){
                    startDayConverted= "0$startDayConverted"
                }
                binding.txtStartDate.setText("$year-$startMonthConverted-$startDayConverted")
            } else {
                var month = month + 1
                var monthConverted = ""+month
                var dayConverted = ""+day

                if(month<10){
                    monthConverted = "0$monthConverted";
                }
                if(day<10){
                    dayConverted = "0$dayConverted"
                }
                binding.txtEndDate.setText("$year-$monthConverted-$dayConverted")
            }

        },
        year,
        month,
        dayOfMonth
    )
    if (type == 0) {
       val startDay = Calendar.getInstance()
        startDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
       datePickerDialog!!.datePicker.minDate = startDay.timeInMillis
    } else {
        val endDay = Calendar.getInstance()
        endDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 2)
       // datePickerDialog!!.datePicker.minDate = endDay.timeInMillis
        datePickerDialog!!.getDatePicker().setMinDate(endDay.getTimeInMillis());
    }
    val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    currentTime = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
    Log.d("TAG", "currentTime:$currentTime ")
    datePickerDialog!!.show()
    //set OK/Cancel buttons color
    //set OK/Cancel buttons color
    datePickerDialog!!.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)
    datePickerDialog!!.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)
}
```

Comment: Use range picker

Comment: thank you for your advise but i need to use android datepicker due to some restrictions

Comment: Use material theme the material date picker provide that option

Comment: Or check this ques
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates