# Calculate date difference in days in Android

Tags: android, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in days.

I have something like:

```
String deadline = "2015-08-15";
```

and I get the current date in:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

For example it would be for today:

> 2015-11-11

How can I calculate the days between these two dates? And what happens if the date is past.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838527/android-java-date-difference-in-days

Comment: It's Not a duplicate because i have two strings.

Comment: Not really. It's Not solved.

Comment: @korunos What did you mean by "not solved"? What are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this

```
public String getDateAgo() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(createdAt);
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long days = getDateDiff(date, now, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        if (days < 7)
            return days + "d";
        else
            return days / 7 + "w";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "ERROR";
}

private long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: very nice soluton! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use jodatime:

```
String date1 = "2015-11-11";
String date2 = "2013-11-11";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(date1);
DateTime d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(date2);
long diffInMillis = d2.getMillis() - d1.getMillis();

Duration duration = new Duration(d1, d2);
int days = duration.getStandardDays();
int hours = duration.getStandardHours();
int minutes = duration.getStandardMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Calendar` Class for this. for past time you can pass day, month and year to Calendar Class and after that you can convert it to `milisecond`. and you can do this for current time. and after that you can convert it to `milisecond`. then you have 2 value with `milisecond` unit. and you can calculate their difference and again you can convert this result `milisecond` to `Date`. a reading of `Calendar` class documentation and it's method can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static long getDatesDifferenceInDays(Date startDate,Date endDate) {
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;
    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    return elapsedDays;
}
```