# How to get Time ago in android?

Tags: java, android, date-difference

I have android program that display the users comment using RecyclerView and CardView. And i have the TextView on every comment that display the time created in this format **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'** and i want the time to be 
displayed like **"1 minutes ago"**, **Now**, **1 month ago**, ...

i tried to implement by using the following codes

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
       // long time = s.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z").getTime();
        long time = 0;
        try {
            time = s.parse(timeNow).getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long now = currentTimeMillis();

        CharSequence ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

Anyone with an idea on how to implement this can help me.

Comment: Search for `android date difference`

Comment: It not solving my problem

Comment: i think this question is not a duplicate

Comment: Youthinks **wrong**. Methinks **it is**. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I got it Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your format fits an ISO 8601 instant. So I suggest you get ThreeTenABP and parse your strings into instant, then use `Duration.between()`. You may need some creative way to display your durations. [Link: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059808/5772882) (found by following the duplicate links).