# LocalDateTime , ZonedDateTime and Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, java-time, date

I have a SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have a domain object with 2 properties (initDate, endDate). I want to create 2 converters to deal with mySQL DB

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class) 
private LocalDateTime initDate;

@Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeAttributeConverter.class) 
private ZonedDateTime endDate;
```

the converter 1 (is OK)

```
@Converter
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return (localDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

This is the one that I want to create

```
@Converter
public class ZonedDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime) {
        return (zoneDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(zoneDateTime));
    }


    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toZonedDateTime());
    }
}
```

But I can't because I have 2 errors:

```
The method valueOf(String) in the type Timestamp is not applicable for the arguments (ZonedDateTime)
```

and the TimeStamp does not have the method `toZonedDateTime()`

and if I don't add any converter for the ZonedDate, JPA creates a table with the type `varbinary(255)`

Comment: Well which time zone do you want it in? (It seems pretty broken than you can convert a `Timestamp` to a `LocalDateTime`, but there we go.) You may well want to go via `Timestamp.toInstant()` and `Timestamp.from(Instant)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) extends `Date` to provide nanosecond accuracy. Neither `Date` nor `Timestamp` are designed to refer to a specific timezone as `ZoneDateTime`.

If you need to convert `ZonedDateTime` -> `Timestamp` you will have to discard the timezone/offset information. E.g.

```
LocalDateTime withoutTimezone = zoneDateTime.toLocalDateTime();
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(withoutTimezone));
```

and for converting `Timestamp` -> `ZonedDateTime` you need to specify an offset:

```
LocalDateTime withoutTimezone = sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
ZonedDateTime withTimezone = withoutTimezone.atZone(ZoneId.of("+03:00"));
```

or timezone:

```
ZonedDateTime withTimezone = withoutTimezone.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

If your intention is to save `ZonedDateTime` variables in the database and preserve the various timezones specified there, I recommend designing your database accordingly. Suggestions:

1. Use a column of type `DATETIME` to save a `LocalDateTime` and a `VARCHAR` saving a timezone like `"Europe/Paris"` or a `SMALLINT` saving an offset in minutes.
2. Convert the `ZonedDateTime` to a `String` and save in a `VARCHAR` column like `"2017-05-16T14:12:48.983682+01:00[Europe/London]"`. You'll then have to parse it when reading from the database.

Comment: Upvoted for the obviously good suggestion of designing the database to hold the time zone information too.

Comment: withoutTimezone.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")) is same with sqlTimestamp.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")), it just simply added timezone.

Answer (score 11):

Jon Skeet said it already:

```
@Override
public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime) {
    return zoneDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.from(zoneDateTime.toInstant());
}

@Override
public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
    return sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Jon also asked the good question, which time zone do you want? I have guessed at `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Obviously a different time zone will give a different result, so I hope you will think twice and will be able to find the right time zone for your purpose.

PS I have reduced the usage of parentheses since I found it more readable with fewer. You can add them back in if you prefer.