# Convert java.sql.Timestamp to Java 8 ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, sql, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

Migrating Joda time to Java 8

Joda:

```
UserObject user = new UserObject()
user.setCreatedAt(new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("columnName")));`
```

Migrating to Java 8

This is my code; it does compile; I am doubtful if it works:

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(rs.getTimestamp("columnName").toLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC),ZoneId.of("UTC")));
```

In some cases, the date is wrong. Any advice?

Comment: What is the database column datatype? Can you give an example of a correct value, as shown in an SQL query and then as `ZonedDateTime`? And then an example of a wrong date, as in the database, with what would have been the correct `ZonedDateTime` and how the actual result differs? “In some cases, the date is wrong” is — frankly — hopelessly vague.

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be working: ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(rs.getTimestamp("column").toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This seems to work:-

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(rs.getTimestamp("columnname").toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
```

Answer (score 36):

## tl;dr

To track a moment in history, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) as the type of your class member variable. Specifically, this moment is seen as a date and time-of-day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
public class UserObject() {
    Instant createdAt ;
    …
    public void setCreatedAt( Instant instantArg ) {
        this.createdAt = instantArg ;
    {
}
```

Usage, capturing the current moment.

```
UserObject user = new UserObject() ;
user.setCreatedAt( Instant.now() ) ;
```

Usage, populating value from database.

```
UserObject user = new UserObject() ;
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( "when_created" , Instant.class ) ;
user.setCreatedAt( instant ) ;
```

[JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) does not require support for [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) (a moment in UTC). If your driver does not support that class, switch to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) which is required.

```
UserObject user = new UserObject() ;
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( "when_created" , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;  
user.setCreatedAt( odt.toInstant() ) ;  // Convert from an `OffsetDateTime` (for any offset-from-UTC) to `Instant` (always in UTC).
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Present to the user, localized for the user-interface.

```
user               // Your business object.
.getCreatedAt()    // Returns a `Instant` object.
.atZone(           // Adjust from UTC to a time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  // Specify the user’s desired/expected time zone.
)                  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
.format(           // Generate a `String` representing the value of date-time object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(
        FormatStyle.FULL   // Specify how long or abbreviated the string.
    )
    .withLocale(   // Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms for localization.
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH 
    )
)                  // Returns a `String`.
```

Notice that [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) has *nothing* to do with time zone, an orthogonal issue. The code above might be for a business person from [Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec) who is traveling in [New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand). She wants to see the wall-clock time used by the [kiwis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi_(people)) around her, but she prefers to read its textual display in her native French. Both time zone and locale are issues best left to presentation only; generally best to use UTC in the rest of your code. Thus, we defined our member variable `createdAt` as an `Instant`, with `Instant` always being in UTC by definition.

## Avoid `java.sql.Timestamp`

- The `java.sql.Timestamp`, along with `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, and `Calendar` are all part of the terribly troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.
- [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) too is now supplanted by the *java.time* classes, as stated in the front page of the project’s site.

### java.time

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html) and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

#### `Instant`

Send the current moment to the database using `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

#### `ZonedDateTime`

To see that same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

#### `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment

> .toLocalDateTime().

**Never involve `LocalDateTime`** class when representing a specific moment in time. The class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It is a vague idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Holy smokes, thanks for the machete to navigate the Java + JDBC Time thicket!

Comment: `getObject(..., Instant.class)` gives `conversion to class java.time.Instant from timestamp not supported` (Java 11)

Comment: @mangusta Yes, I need to fix that. Support for `Instant` is optional. The JDBC 4.2 spec requires support for `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
rs.getTimestamp("columnName").toInstant()
    .atZone(ZoneId.[appropriate-zone-ID-here])
```

You need to use a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) appropriate to the region (you may try with [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) for a start).

For more details about the differences between various Java-Time APIs, see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/2032415).